# Create vars with "$i" value on a for cicle

Tags: php, forms, for-loop

```
<form>
  <?php
    for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
       print '<input ... name="'.$until.$i.'">...
   print '<input ... name="'.$quantity.$i.'">...
}
  ?>
</form>
```

Is it possible with this for:

```
for($p=1; $p<=3; $p++){

    $until.$p = $_POST['until'.$p]; // not required
    $quantity.$p = $_POST['quantity'.$p]; // required
}
```

to create vars that will have these names?

```
$until1
$quantity1
...
$until3
$quantity3
```

My solution won't obviously work...

Answer (score 5):

Use an array instead. Then you can have `$until[$p]` for example.

Comment: i was just about to write this, beat me!

Answer (score 1):

Use `${'until'.$p}` to do exactly want you want.

Comment: Thank you! I thought about the array option, but this is what I was searching for! Can you give me some references about this? Thank you again!

Comment: @user2120569 To be honest, array solution suggested by others is better, but this way also exists. :) http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: i'll keep it in mind! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Array, most definitely. Remember, with PHP you can add elements dynamically. On an aesthetic note, "until" is a reserved word in several languages, as part of program controls (e.g., if-then-else, do-while). Consider using variable names that represent the function and/or type of data.